# Unusual Behavior: Tailwind CSS Integration with Bit.dev Components in React Project

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, bit, tailwind-ui, bit.dev

I'm currently experiencing an issue with integrating *Bit.dev* components that utilize Tailwind CSS into my React project. Despite diligently following the steps outlined in the *Bit.dev* blog, I'm encountering an unexpected problem.

Here's the context: I created an initial *Bit.dev* project using the command **`bit new react my-proj -a teambit.react/react-env -d my.scope`**. Following that, I configured my environment according to the instructions provided in this blog: **[Integrating Tailwind CSS and Bit for Component Styling](https://bit.dev/blog/integrating-tailwind-css-and-bit-for-component-styling-lgntqstt/)**.

Afterward, I developed a component with styling with **`className="w-10 h-10",`** performed a **`bit tag`** & **`bit export`**. Interestingly, the preview on *Bit.cloud* displayed the component without any issues; the styling classes were applied correctly.

However, when I imported this *Bit.dev* component into my React project (which already had Tailwind properly set up). The component did not behave as expected. **It's puzzling that when I attempted to create a simple component with the classes "w-10 h-10" (following the same pattern as the *Bit.dev* component) on a `<div>`, suddenly the previously non-functional *Bit.dev* component started working as intended, with proper width and height.**

In essence, the styling classes only seem to work when used in another component – for instance, applying the styles to a separate **`<div>`** element.

I have also posted two issues on Bit's GitHub repository related to my complaint. One of them was closed due to a misunderstanding, while the other one is still open and awaiting a response after they requested the Tailwind config code from my React project and the config from my Bit project.

- [Issue [#7750]](https://github.com/teambit/bit/issues/7750) closed
- [Issue [#7751]](https://github.com/teambit/bit/issues/7751) re-open

You can also take a look there and discuss the matter if you don't mind. I have explained the situation there in an organized manner

Comment: can anyone help me navigate the bit dev documentation for integrating tailwind. I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the issue, you must be **`including node_modules/@your-bit-org in the content section of the Tailwind CSS configuration`**

Adding this directory is crucial for correctly applying styling classes from *Bit.dev* components in the React project.

after installing your bit component into react project, check your location of components in node_modules and add this to your tailwind config

```
/** tailwind.config.js (in your react project) **/

export default {
  content: [
    './**/*.{jsx,tsx}',
    './node_modules/@your/components.**/*.{jsx,tsx}', //add this
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```